# Materials for Qiskit Exam

Tags: qiskit

I spent a few months studying from the following materials but still failed the Qiskit exam (38/60 = 63%). I will be retaking next week so I'm looking for recommendations for any materials I may have missed.I took a class in university so I skipped the first section of the Qiskit textbook.

- practice exams: https://github.com/pratjz/IBM-Qiskit-Exam-Prep
- 1 minute qiskit:  https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLOFEBzvs-VvpOCmJ9BonUhf7NYB4d1p0e

I've noticed in the syllabus: https://learn.qiskit.org/syllabus/S9P-7GP it says to study the APU reference for Terra and Aer (links broken). Are these the correct links:

- https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/aer/apidocs/aer.html
- https://qiskit.org/documentation/apidoc/terra.html

and is there a more concise list that is relevant to the qiskit exam? Terra has a lot that I would need to memorize...